# Exception when using composite component with <p:datatable>

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I'm new in JSF and i would like to create composite component with  nested, the thing is when i declare these attributes like that (in above code) i received this message ***javax.servlet.ServletException: Argument is not an array*** means that the attribute **itemSelection** JSF didn't considere this attribute like Array. I don't know if my component is well declared if you've got some ideas to help. thanks. Here is the code :

```
<composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="itemValue" default="#{utilisateurController.items}" type="javax.faces.model.ListDataModel" required="false"/>
        <composite:attribute name="itemSelection" default="#{utilisateurController.selectedItems}" type="com.netescape.entities.Utilisateur[]" required="false"/>
        <composite:attribute name="actionEdit" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" default="#{utilisateurController.prepareEdit(item)}" required="false"/>
        <composite:attribute name="actionView" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" default="#{utilisateurController.prepareView(item)}" required="false"/>
        <composite:attribute name="actionDestroy" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" default="#{utilisateurController.destroy(item)}" required="false"/>
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <h:form prependId="false" id="formListUtilisateur" >

            <p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.itemValue}" var="item" paginator="true" rows="10"  
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
                         {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                         selection="#{cc.attrs.itemSelection}" rowKey="#{item.id}">
```